# Can't figure out how to use $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

If have an application controller. In this controller I call a resource service called "saveGame". The saveGame has a property called "resolved". I initialize this property with *false*. When the promise resolves (save game is loaded), I set the resolved property to *true*.

Above part works.

Now I inject the saveGame service in my MainCtrl.
If I run the code locally it works, because the saveGame resolves almost instantly. But if I turn on latency - mimicking a very slow connection. The saveGame won't resolve in time and I need to wait for it.

Here is my code:

```
application
    .controller('MainCtrl',
        ['$scope', 'saveGame', function ($scope, saveGame) {
            'use strict';

            // At this point the savegame should be resolved
            // If not we need to wait for it.
            $scope.$watch(saveGame.resolved, function ( newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log( newVal + '-' + oldVal ); // #1
                if(newVal !== undefined ){
                    //do your stuff here...
                    console.log("do your stuff"); // #2
                }
            });
```

So the *newVal*, *oldVal* at #1 come out as undefined.
The console log at #2 never triggers.

For completeness, my saveGame service looks like this:

```
application
    .factory('saveGame',
        ['$resource', 'config', function ($resource, config) {
            'use strict';

            var _resolved = false;
            var _location = {};

            var _load = function (playerId) {
                var res;
                if (config.getSetting('use-mockup')) {
                    // Use mockup data
                    // $resource returns a class representation
                    res = $resource('data/mockup/savegame/player:id.json');
                } else {
                    // TODO: Use real API
                }
                // This will return a promise!
                return res.get({id: playerId}).$promise;
            };

            var _save = function (stuff) {
                return stuff;
            };

            return {
                load: _load,
                save: _save,
                location: _location,
                resolved: _resolved
            };
        }]);
```

And the part in my appCtrl like this:

```
// Load the savegame resource
            var promise = saveGame.load(1); // PlayerId
            promise.then(function (resource) {
                // savegame resource was loaded and resolved
                saveGame.location = resource.location;
                saveGame.resolved = true;
            });
```

So I know I am doing something wrong, but I just can't figure out what?
Same help would be really appreciated.

Comment: how are you getting the data in your saveGame service? Maybe it is async in nature?

Comment: I updated my question with the saveGame service code and the part of the application controller that inits it. @TarunDugar

Comment: are you sure you can watch a service's variable in the controller? How abour assiging saveGame.resolved to controller's scope variable and having a watch on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
        $scope.$watch(function () { return saveGame.resolved; }, function ( newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log( newVal + '-' + oldVal ); // #1
            if(newVal !== undefined ){
                //do your stuff here...
                console.log("do your stuff"); // #2
            }
        });
```

You have to use string as first parameters of watch or function with return value. If you use string 'a.b.c', AngularJS comparing will compare `$scope.a.b.c` in current and next cycle. If you use function there, AngularJS will compare result of functions.

May be better way here is to update `saveGame` service and return promise in it. And everywhere you need result of saveGame you will use this:

```
module.factory('saveService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        doSave: function () {
            return $http.get(params);
        }
    }
}])

module.controller('MainCtrl', ['saveService', function (saveService) {
    saveService.doSave().then(function onSuccess() {
        // handle something after save
    });
}])
```

Comment: Wow. That worked... There is one small mistake in your code:
{ return saveGame.resolved; }) <-- you need to remove this.

Comment: As for the saveGame service. Tnx for the tip. I will rewrite it, to resolve it internally. Much cleaner that way!